# MySQL / PHP ordering rows based on field

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, group-by

I need to set a value for column race_order based on the time in `race_time`. This needs to be on a per `class_id` basis.

I have tried a few different query's to get the result I'm looking for, but I am running up against a wall on this one.

```
Column  Type
time_tracking_id (Primary)  int(1)
event_id    int(1)
class_id    int(1)
race_type   varchar(1)
race_nbr    int(1)
race_time   varchar(10)
race_order  int(1)
```

See this sqlfiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e2e6/1/0

This is the result I am looking for:

```
time_tracking_id    event_id    class_id    race_type   race_nbr    race_time   race_order
        5              113          14       (null)        21        121.0000       1
        6              113          14       (null)        22        124.0000       2
        1              113          17       (null)        25        120.0000       1
        2              113          17       (null)        26        180.0000       2
```

Comment: you sqlfiddle doesn't work.. but wht do you mean for  "I need to set a value" ? a select ? and update ? explain better

Comment: Not sure why the fiddle isn't working for you, works fine for me.

Yes, I need to update the field race_order to a "ranking" based on the class_id and race_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very fast, but it is works if race_time is unique for every class_id:

```
SELECT
  time_tracking_id, 
  event_id,
  class_id,
  race_type,
  race_nbr,
  race_time,
  1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_time_tracking t2
   WHERE t2.class_id = tbl_time_tracking.class_id 
   AND t2.race_time < tbl_time_tracking.race_time) AS race_order
FROM
  tbl_time_tracking
ORDER BY class_id, 
         race_time
```

Comment: Yes, they will be.. 

Works great. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Execution time isn't really important as I'll typically only be working on 4 to 8 rows at a time.

Comment: *"It is not very fast"* - hey, least you're honest ;-) good job.

Comment: I ran it in place with the rest of the parts of the app and it's definitely not an issue. Fast enough.